# Turbogears configuration

Tags: turbogears

installed Turbogears and cannot seem to configure it, with its test file from the site. After the installation i am running the command: python myapp.py, but i get the error tg module doesnt exist. I have installed tg with pip. In the Pythonpath is also the site packages dir where tg also is.
how can i resolve this?
These are the imports:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from tg import MinimalApplicationConfigurator
from tg import expose, TGController
```

Comment: now it found tg but cannot import MinimalApplicationConfigurator

Comment: or exposed , TGController

Comment: so what i am doing is i am trying to run a py file in my projects directory with pipenv shell activated. This is also not working